# Simple Calculator in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I want to add two numbers when the user presses/enters `"1"` from keyboard, subtract when the user presses `"2"`, and multiply when user presses `"3"`.

```
def add(x,y)
  return x + y
end
def sub(x,y)
  return x - y
end
def multiply(x,y)
  return x * y
end

puts"Enter a First Number"
num1=gets.chomp

puts"Enter a Second Number"
num2=gets.chomp

puts"Press 1,2 or 3 from your keyboard"
choice=gets.chomp

if choice == "1"
  puts(num1,"+",num2, "=", add(num1,num2))
elsif choice == "2"
  puts(num1,"-",num2,"=",sub(num1,num2))
elsif choice == "3"
  puts(num1,"*",num2,"=",multiply(num1,num2))
else
  puts"Invalid Input/Choice"
end
gets
```

I have some errors in my code. When I press `"1",` I give the input like this:

```
first number=2
second number=3
```

but the result is 2+3=23, while it should be actually 2+3=5. There are the some error in subtract and multiply too. If, anybody can solve this problem, then I will be greatful.

Comment: What kind of variables are num1 and num2? Are they numerics? What happens when you do num1 + num2?

Answer (score 3):

[@notulysses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985484/simple-calculator-in-ruby#29985512) has already gave you the solution which is correct. I just wanted to show how you are getting the result of `23`

```
 > "2" + "3" # as string
 => "23" 
 > "2".to_i + "3".to_i # convert string to integer
 => 5
```

In addition to your this point:

> There are the some error in subtract and multiply too

As subtract and multiply can not perform on String. That's why you are getting an error: Let me show you that also:

```
 > "2" - "3"
 # NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "2":String
 > "2" * "3"
 # TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

If you convert the user input from string to integer by using `to_i` method you will get proper result as well as you will not get any error. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should apply [`.to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) to convert user's input to integer (`gets.to_i`), otherwise they are treated as strings and in case of `+` operator concatenated (in other cases you should get errors concerning `undefined method` and `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`).

Comment: This is a bad answer. Gagan Gami's answer is the good answer.

Comment: It may make more sense here to use Integer() which is more picky for converting objects to integers.  For example, for strings, "1" => 1 but "one" => ArgumentError.  In the case of to_i, if the string is not a string representation of an integer, 0 is returned. 0 is also returned for nil.to_i.  So if the user enters: "one" "two" "1"  the program will return 0.

Comment: @sawa: Care to elaborate?

Comment: `chomp` before `to_i` is redundant. Only ignorant people do that.